# What is the relationship between the prediction interval of an ARIMA(p,d,q) and the prediction interval of the original variable

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, prediction-interval

The title may be enough, I want to know what is the relationship between the prediction interval of an ARIMA(p,d,q) and the prediction interval of the original variable. Lets say that d = 1, so that I would work with diff(y) and obtain its prediction intervals, given this, how do these intervals relate to those for y.

Thanks in advance